# How can we make asynchronous REST api call in Java?

Tags: java, spring, rest, resttemplate, asyncresttemplate

I am using Spring RestTemplate and want to make a call to another service that doesn't return any response body. So, I don't want to wait for the response. So, it's just fire and forget, and continue with the remaining code. I am thinking of creating a new Thread to do this but really not sure what's the correct approach.

Comment: Why not to do request and very short timeout? Do you still get status code as a return and you need it for request verification?

Comment: HTTP Response code would be there but don't need it as failed calls ( like 502 ) would not matter much. Basically, this end point is invoked just to say something like  "hey, we have got this new order, keep the details ready for quick future lookups"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct approach is to execute the async with a callback (using [DeferredResult](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/request/async/DeferredResult.html), like this (assuming we have a class `someClass` that we want to retrieve from the API:

```
@GetMapping(path = "/testingAsync")
public DeferredResult<String> value() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, TimeoutException {
   AsyncRestTemplate restTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate();
   String baseUrl = "http://someUrl/blabla";
   HttpHeaders requestHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
   requestHeaders.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
   String value = "";

   HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity("parameters", requestHeaders);
   final DeferredResult<String> result = new DeferredResult<>();
   ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<someClass>> futureEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity(baseUrl, someClass.class);

   futureEntity.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<someClass>>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<someClass> result) {
         System.out.println(result.getBody().getName());
         result.setResult(result.getBody().getName());
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
         result.setErrorResult(ex.getMessage());
      }
  });

  return result;
}
```

Comment: It's throwing error as 'org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity cannot be cast to org.springframework.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture' for this line "ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<InitiateEventResponseVO>> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, request, InitiateEventResponseVO.class);

Comment: `AsyncRestTemplate` is Deprecated

Answer (score 14):

If you use Java 11, java support asynchronous HTTP Client. Asynchronous client using [CompletableFuture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html) in the back. You can see [javadoc](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/net/httpclient/intro.html).

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create("http://openjdk.java.net/"))
            .timeout(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .POST(BodyPublishers.ofFile(Paths.get("file.json")))
            .build();

    client.sendAsync(request, BodyHandlers.ofString())
            .thenApply(response -> { System.out.println(response.statusCode());
                return response; } )
            .thenApply(HttpResponse::body)
            .thenAccept(System.out::println);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can use to fire the request using the AsyncRestTemplate

The simplest way is just like restTemplate and call exchange method:

```
AsyncRestTemplate asyncRestTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("firstName","testUser");
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(json.toString(), headers);

Class<String> responseType = String.class;
ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> future = asyncRestTemplate.exchange("https://xxxxx.com/", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity,responseType );

// If you want for the result then you can use 
 try {
        //waits for the result
        ResponseEntity<String> entity = future.get();
        //prints body source code for the given URL
        log.info(entity.getBody());
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If we want to play with the failure (fallback scenario) or success in that case we can use the below code :

```
AsyncRestTemplate asyncRestTemplate = new AsyncRestTemplate();
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("firstName","testUser");
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<String>(json.toString(), headers);

 //final DeferredResult<String> result = new DeferredResult<>();
 ListenableFuture<ResponseEntity<String>> future = 
 asyncRestTemplate.postForEntity("https://xxxx.com", requestEntity, String.class);

  future.addCallback(new ListenableFutureCallback<ResponseEntity<String>>() {

 @Override
 public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
// insert into the table or log or some other decision
 log.info(ex.getMessage());
 }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ResponseEntity<String> result) {
            log.info(result.getBody());
            log.info("Sucess");
        }
    });
```

Comment: AsyncRestTemplate is deprecated.